# Android get REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE extras with Glide

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide library to manage the Bitmap captured by the camera.

Here the working code (without Glide)

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try{
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And here my try with Glide:

```
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try{
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(extras.get("data")).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).fitCenter().into(imageView);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

My imageView remains empty.

Comment: Why would you need Glide here? You have the `Bitmap`. You do not need to load the `Bitmap` in the background.

Comment: I would like to prevent a bad memory usage. Mine understand of Glide usage is about zero absolute. Sry man I'm really terrified from Java.OutOfMemory exception and i was trying to apply Glide library as much more as I can.

Comment: @CommonsWare by the way, and sry for my insistence, there is a way to do it?

Comment: Is there a way to do what? Your first code snippet is as frugal on memory as you are going to get for getting a photo from a third-party camera app.

Comment: @CommonsWare To assign the ImageView bitmap using the Glide Library instead creating a Bitmap object.

Comment: No, that is not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, thanks anyway. I will continue to use my code.

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround by using the real image:

```
    else if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try{
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            //InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(u);
            //BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize=3; //decrease decoded image
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).fitCenter().into(imageView);
            //extras.clear();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```